# Local UserNotifications at specific moment in time and day? Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, usernotifications

I have an To-Do-App. In Core Data I store some task with id, taskName, taskDate. Now I want to instruct my app to do local UserNotification every Monday and Tuesday at taskDate (e.g. 09:00 am). I try to do it with UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger, but this don't work.

Can anyone tell me, how could I add an specific time on Monday and Tuesday to fire the Notification?

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func notifyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    scheduleNotification(inSeconds: 20, title: "title", subtitle: "subtitle", body: "", completion: { success in
        if success {
            print("Successfully scheduled notification")
        } else {
            print("Erro scheduling notifiation")
        }
    })
}

func scheduleNotification(inSeconds: TimeInterval, title: String, subtitle: String, body:String, completion: @escaping (_ Success: Bool) -> ()) {

    let titleIn = title
    let subtitleIn = subtitle
    let bodyIn = body

    // Add an attachment
    let myImage = "IconNotify"
    guard let imageUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: myImage, withExtension: "png") else {
        completion(false)
        return
    }

    var attachement: UNNotificationAttachment

    attachement = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "myNotification", url: imageUrl, options: .none)

    let nofif = UNMutableNotificationContent()

    //ONLY FOR EXTENSION
    nofif.categoryIdentifier = "myNotificationCategory"

    nofif.title = titleIn
    nofif.subtitle = subtitleIn
    nofif.body = "TaskBody"
    nofif.badge = 1
    nofif.attachments = [attachement]

    let nofifTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: inSeconds, repeats: false)


    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myNotification", content: nofif, trigger: nofifTrigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completion(false)
        } else {
            completion(true)
        }
    })
}
```

In the AppDelegate I do this:

```
private func configureUserNotifications() {

    let okAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "okBump", title: "Ok", options: [])
    let dismissAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "dismiss", title: "Remind me later", options: [])

    let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "myNotificationCategory", actions: [okAction, dismissAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])
}
}
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Response received for \(response.actionIdentifier)")
    completionHandler()
} }
```

Thanks so much.